# removing the brackets and quotes from active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When a user pulls data from the DB onto the screen which all work great but looks naff because it contains brackets etc as you can see below.

```
[["100056", "lion bar"]]
[["100055", "milky way"]]
[["100054", "mars bar"]]
```

this is my controller code

```
@last_posts = Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(1).pluck(:big_id, :customer)
```

my view is only this at the moment.

```
<%= @last_posts %><br>  
<%= @last_posts_but1 %><br>
<%= @last_posts_but2 %><br>
<%= @last_posts_but3 %><br>
<%= @last_posts_but4 %><br>
<%= @last_posts_but5 %><br>
```

Comment: I think you are being returned an array of array's as a response. Can you post your activerecord query here.

Comment: As you can you can see, while you are limiting to 1 using limit, you are trying to retrieve big_id and customer. 
It is simialar to `select big_id, customer from posts` which returns an array of arrays.
Pluck directly converts database result into an array without constructing active record  objects.
You can access the attributes as @last_posts.first which gives ["100056", "lion bar"]

Comment: not sure I fully understand I would like it to just say 100056 lion bar

Comment: Then access the returned array's individual components by index.

Comment: You could do @last_posts.map(:&first) or @last_posts.map{|row| |row0|}

Comment: @user944938, I like the user of map with activerecord support

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(1).pluck(:big_id, :customer).flatten
```

Will return what you're looking for. `flatten` gets rid of nested arrays. `first` also works, but you know that your query will return no more than one record. For edge cases, you won't have to do nil checking after `flatten` because calling it on an empty array returns an empty array.

Also, the `select` method will return an array of active record objects that only have the `big_id` and `customer` attributes populated, not an array of arrays.

**NOTE:**. If you're looking to change the limit to anything greater than 1, `flatten` will not work.

Comment: ok .flatten removes the array of array brackets.. but how do I get it too just read 100056 lion bar.... i.e no brackets or quotes. Remembering that I am limiting 1 only because it is a feature of the web app to view the last submission.

Comment: Oh. Why didn't you state that in the question? `Post.order('created_at DESC').limit(1).pluck(:big_id, :customer).flatten.join(' ')`

Comment: sorry when I said I didn't want brackets I meant all of them.... however Mike what you have advised has worked a treat....  so Many Many thanks for that ... I can't beleive it... seems so simple...  I just need to go away and understand what .flatten and .join actually mean...  just so I understand the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = [[["100056", "lion bar"]],
         [["100055", "milky way"]],
         [["100054", "mars bar"]]]

puts result.map { |x| x.flatten.join(' ') }
# => 100056 lion bar
# => 100055 milky way
# => 100054 mars bar
```

Comment: ok i'm not sure I fully understand this bit. should this go in the controller?

Comment: Since you did not post your view, it is hard to know what changes need to be done there. If you add this to your controller, you'll get the output I wrote on the console, I guess that is _not_ what you want

Answer (score 1):

To summarize comments above:

As you can you can see, while you are limiting to 1 using limit, you are trying to retrieve big_id and customer. It is simialar to `select big_id, customer from posts` which returns an array of arrays.

Pluck directly converts database result into an array without constructing active record objects.

You can access the attributes as @last_posts.first which gives ["100056", "lion bar"]

```
@last_posts.map(:&first) or @last_posts.map{|row| |row0|}
```

Comment: will this only remove the end brackets? ideally I want rid of all brackets and quotes. i.e 100056 lion bar

Comment: Im not sure of what you mean by getting rid of brackets and quotes. I can see that you are storing the data 100056 as string in the database. You should be changing that first into integer or float depending on your request. Strings in ruby/rails by default have "". DO you have a specific reason to get rid of brackets and quotes?

Comment: so it only reads 100056 lion bar not ["100056", "lion bar"] the reason for removing them is that when it is displayed in the html pages it looks terrible.

Comment: I use <%= @last_posts[0] %> to display array elements and I never encountered "" appearing there.. Can you post your view code. Are you using puts or something..

Comment: ok @last_posts[0] does remove the quotes and the brackets.. so looks much better except it remover the name of the chocolate bar also so just displays 100056   ---  i've never been so close.

Comment: <%= @last_post[1] %> will display name of the chocolate bar too.. In array indexing starts from zero. So you can use the following <%= @last_post[0]%> , <%= @last_post[1]%>.